# ECONNRESET error in postman while trying to make a post request to an azure web app

Tags: azure, postman, azure-web-app-service, fastapi, http-status-code-400

so I created a fastapi app and uploaded it to azure as a web app.
Now im trying to test one of the endpoints as a post request in postman that recieves an audio file, and 2 params.
But as I run it, I recieve an error: Error: read ECONNRESET (from postmans console), and as a response:
{
"detail": "There was an error parsing the body"
}

and this log from the azure log stream:
2024-03-17T19:02:36.7547238Z WARNING: Did not find boundary character 206 at index 2
2024-03-17T19:02:36.7549282Z INFO:     169.254.129.1:12719 - "POST /transcribe?song_name=wait&singer=hadar HTTP/1.1" 400 Bad Request

The postman calls for the other endpoint works (a simple get that returns a success message)
Also the same post endpoint runs localy and also directly from docker.

I tried to test the endpoint in postman and it couldnt parse the request body (that contains an audio file)

Comment: If it is possible, can you share your code or GitHub repository.

Comment: yes, this is the repository
https://github.com/LeeJaichenco/myAPI

Comment: How did you deploy your web app to Azure?

Comment: pushed the docker image to an ACR and then used it for a web app

Answer (score 0):

> Did not find boundary character 206 at index 2 2024-03-17T19:02:36.7549282Z INFO: 169.254.129.1:12719 - "POST /transcribe?song_name=wait&singer=hadar HTTP/1.1" 400 Bad Request

- This error occurs if the request body is not in the correct format or too large. Reduce the data that is being sent in the request.
- Check the request body to make sure that it is in the correct format and none of the required fields are missed.
- In Postman, select **form-data** and type as *File* and upload the audio file.

[image]

> Error: read ECONNRESET (from postmans console), and as a response: { "detail": "There was an error parsing the body" }.

- This error occurs if the connection was reset while reading data or the invalid format of request body.
- The boundary character is used to separate the different parts of a multipart/form-data request body.

Deploy the application to Azure again through a different way (VSCode or Azure CLI) and check the logs of the Azure App Service for the complete error details:
Also increase the timeout value for the client.

- Enable Application Logging in `Azure App Service=>Application Logging=>Select File System`.

[image]

- Browse the application URL and check the logs in `Azure App Service=>Log Stream`:

[image]